# Window function for average

Tags: sql, window-functions, presto

I have this table `timestamp_table` and I'm using Presto SQL

```
timestamp  |  id
2021-01-01 10:00:00 | 2456
```

I would like to compute the number of unique IDs in the last 24 and 48 hours and I thought this could be achieved with window functions but I'm struggling. This is my proposed solution, but it needs work

SELECT COUNT(id) OVER (PARTITION BY timestamp ORDER BY timestamp RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL '24' HOUR PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)

Comment: Your SQL uses `AVG`, which was not part of the requirement.  Try completing the test case, with enough data.  Then show the expected output you wish to generate, given that data.  If you really want some average, add that clearly to the question.  Note: `COUNT` without a corresponding `GROUP BY` will just produce one count for the entire set of rows, which leaves your window function without much to work with.

Comment: `PARTITION BY timestamp` will be a problem, since only rows within the same timestamp will be considered by the count for each row.  Did you mean to partition by the id?  It's hard to tell. .... or just remove the `PARTITION BY` clause.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably having trouble due to the `PARTITION BY` clause, since the `COUNT` will only apply to rows within the same `timestamp` values.

Try something like this, as a starting point:

[The fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=eb313136ba04e3245c223cadc5d3697c)

```
SELECT *
     , COUNT(id) OVER (ORDER BY timestamp RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL '24' HOUR PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
     , MIN(id)   OVER (ORDER BY timestamp RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL '24' HOUR PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
  FROM tbl
;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can't get data for both time intervals by one table scan. Because row that is in last 24 hours must be in both groups: 24 hours and 48 hours. So you must do 2 request or union them.

```
select 'h24', count(distinct id)
from timestamp_table
where timestamp < current_timestamp and timestamp >= date_add(day, -1, current_timestamp)
union all
select 'h48', count(distinct id) 
from timestamp_table
where timestamp < current_timestamp and timestamp >= date_add(day, -2, current_timestamp)
```